# How can I disable SSE in GCC?

Tags: gcc, arm, debian, sse

I'm trying to make a package in debian (squeeze, armel). Problem is, my GCC seems to have set -msse2 which is unsupported on ARM, and I have no idea how to disable it. How can I change GCC's default flags to disable this? Thanks.

Full error:

```
Building CXX object frameworks/CoreLib/CMakeFiles/.....cpp.o

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-msse2"

make[2] \*\*\* [fframeworks/CoreLib/CMakeFiles/.....cpp.o] Error 1

make[1] \*\*\* [frameworks/CoreLib/CMakeFiles/.....dir/all] Error 2

make \*\*\* [all] Error 2
```

thing is, none of the files mention have -msse2 in them, anywhere, which is why I think the compiler might be to blame.

Comment: *all* of x86 is unsupported on ARM, not just SSE. Solution: actually compile for ARM.

Comment: I know, but I would still like to disable the sse flag on my arm system; how do I do that?

Comment: Did you install an ARM crosscompiler?  And are you sure that one is getting used (ie, is it in the path before the native one)?

Comment: I, uh...I just did apt-get install gcc. Was that not right? Sorry, I'm pretty new to building things from source.

Comment: @Will what ARM are you compiling for ?

Comment: ARM9, I'm pretty sure; it's a nexus 7.

Comment: You need a cross compiler toolchain, look here for [some pointers and downloads](http://elinux.org/Toolchains#Embedded_Debian_cross-tools_packages) for Debian systems

Comment: The ARM9 is a very old processor. If given the option, you will probably want to compile for a Cortex-A9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MMX, SSE an SSE2 are Intel/AMD specific extensions that are not supported on ARM, ARM has it's own NEON SIMD extensions. It seems to me like you're trying to cross-compile a program for ARM and using the *native* toochain, for that you will need a toolchain for the target platform. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-arm-toolchain/) on how to install an ARM toolchain that might help

Edit: now that I see the error, the Makefile is passing `-msse2` to gcc, you should read the instructions for compiling that package to ARM see if that is even possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I definitely have the armel version of gcc installed, which is why I'm confused about the sse flag being set. All I want to do is take '-msse2' out of the default command line options.

Comment: @Will you're missing the point, if the toolchain is for ARM it shouldn't have that option at all

Comment: @Will it could be that you're not invoking the correct gcc, it should be called `arm-xxx-xxx-gcc`

Comment: The folder in /usr/lib/gcc is 'arm-linux-gnuabi', so I think it's an ARM toolchain. Maybe the option is being invoked in the files I'm trying to build. Thanks for the help, in any case.

Comment: @Will try `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` or `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` on the command line

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I'll go scour the makefile. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Will you're welcome, but note that editing the Makefile won't just make it work, the code might not be portable, so you should see first if there's a way to compile it for ARM, start with the `README` and then google.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I guess I'll go scour the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else ends up here: 
I ran in a similar pbm, it was due to the configure script not properly treating the arm case. the solution that worked for me was to run `configure` with the option `--disable-sse2`